# Can mobile client get response from server using unbounded service in android?

Tags: android

I am using unbounded service for sending the request to server but it is showing ***Network Main Thread Exception***. Now i am applying the same logic with Async Task its working fine. Can we get response from server by using unbounded service ?

Comment: Are you perform network operation into onStatCommand?

Comment: You can do it but it is not a good practice see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9289190/6869086

Comment: @an_droid_dev i am performing network operation in onStartCommand() i want to hit some url and get the JSON as a response from onStartCommand() without using Asynctask inside onStartCommand() or any thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you are doing a network operation on the main thread, and this is not allowed on Android 3.0 and above. Even though it is in a service, services are run on the UI thread unless you specifically launch them in another thread or create a thread inside it.

You can fix this by running the task in a service off the main UI thread, by using a Thread or an AsyncTask.

Try creating a new thread in onStartCommand()

Comment: Thank you Arun jee.

Comment: If that answered your question, please accept the answer